# Maximum number of tile possible in 2048 game?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Ok my question is what is the maximum number of tile we can make in the 2048 game assuming we were really lucky and got all 4 number tiles and got the new squares exactly where we needed them?

Comment: Clearly, infinity.

Comment: Not exactly sure of the rules of the game but so far as I have seen the new tile added is always a 2 or a 4.  So I think the previous comment is wrong - and if it's right, it surely is not "clearly" right.

Comment: nbunis no, it can't be infinity, to make a 2^n you need two 2^{n-1} and so to make a 2^100 you would need at least 100 spaces....